# Draw round corners on top left top right bottom left bottom right using Path and RectF in Android

Tags: android, imageview, rounded-corners

By making a [custom ImageView](https://stackoverflow.com/a/40150715/2069407) and override the onDraw method with the following will make the ImageView to have rounded corners. Reference

```
@Override
protected void onDraw(Canvas canvas) {
    float radius = getContext().getResources().getDimension(R.dimen.round_corner_radius);
    Path path = new Path();
    RectF rect = new RectF(0, 0, this.getWidth(), this.getHeight());
    path.addRoundRect(rect, radius, radius, Path.Direction.CW);
    canvas.clipPath(path);
    super.onDraw(canvas);
}
```

How can I selectively make the round corners instead of making all four corners round. For example, only making the top left and top right corners round and leave the bottom corners intact. Here is a [solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5252726/2069407) to do to through Bitmap. I am looking for doing it in this onDraw method and only using Path and RectF.

Answer (score 33, accepted):

There is a `Path#addRoundRect()` overload that takes a `float` array of eight values wherein we can specify the x- and y-radius for each of the four corners. These values are in [x, y] pairs, starting at the top-left corner, and going clockwise around the rest. For those corners we want rounded, we set both values of the pair to the radius value, and leave them at zero for those we don't.

As an illustrative example, a simple method that will return a `Path` that can be used in your snippet:

```
private Path getPath(float radius, boolean topLeft, boolean topRight,
                     boolean bottomRight, boolean bottomLeft) {

    final Path path = new Path();
    final float[] radii = new float[8];

    if (topLeft) {
        radii[0] = radius;
        radii[1] = radius;
    }

    if (topRight) {
        radii[2] = radius;
        radii[3] = radius;
    }

    if (bottomRight) {
        radii[4] = radius;
        radii[5] = radius;
    }

    if (bottomLeft) {
        radii[6] = radius;
        radii[7] = radius;
    }

    path.addRoundRect(new RectF(0, 0, getWidth(), getHeight()),
                      radii, Path.Direction.CW);

    return path;
}
```

Per your example description, rounding the top-left and top-right corners:

```
@Override
protected void onDraw(Canvas canvas) {
    float radius = getContext().getResources().getDimension(R.dimen.round_corner_radius);
    Path path = getPath(radius, true, true, false, false);
    canvas.clipPath(path);
    super.onDraw(canvas);
}
```

As always, I would recommend keeping the `onDraw()` method as tight as possible, moving anything that doesn't absolutely have to be there elsewhere. The resource value for the radius, for instance, could be retrieved in the constructor, and kept in a field. Furthermore, the `Path` could be constructed only when necessary; i.e., when the `View`'s size changes, or when the radius or chosen corners change.

Since I put together a simple custom `ImageView` to test this, I'll include it here, as it demonstrates the above points. This custom `View` also offers XML attributes that allow the corner radius and the rounded corners to be set in your layout.

```
public class RoundishImageView extends ImageView {

    public static final int CORNER_NONE = 0;
    public static final int CORNER_TOP_LEFT = 1;
    public static final int CORNER_TOP_RIGHT = 2;
    public static final int CORNER_BOTTOM_RIGHT = 4;
    public static final int CORNER_BOTTOM_LEFT = 8;
    public static final int CORNER_ALL = 15;

    private static final int[] CORNERS = {CORNER_TOP_LEFT,
                                          CORNER_TOP_RIGHT,
                                          CORNER_BOTTOM_RIGHT,
                                          CORNER_BOTTOM_LEFT};

    private final Path path = new Path();
    private int cornerRadius;
    private int roundedCorners;

    public RoundishImageView(Context context) {
        this(context, null);
    }

    public RoundishImageView(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
        this(context, attrs, 0);
    }

    public RoundishImageView(Context context, AttributeSet attrs, int defStyleAttr) {
        super(context, attrs, defStyleAttr);

        TypedArray a = context.obtainStyledAttributes(attrs, R.styleable.RoundishImageView);
        cornerRadius = a.getDimensionPixelSize(R.styleable.RoundishImageView_cornerRadius, 0);
        roundedCorners = a.getInt(R.styleable.RoundishImageView_roundedCorners, CORNER_NONE);
        a.recycle();
    }

    public void setCornerRadius(int radius) {
        if (cornerRadius != radius) {
            cornerRadius = radius;
            setPath();
            invalidate();
        }
    }

    public int getCornerRadius() {
        return cornerRadius;
    }

    public void setRoundedCorners(int corners) {
        if (roundedCorners != corners) {
            roundedCorners = corners;
            setPath();
            invalidate();
        }
    }

    public boolean isCornerRounded(int corner) {
        return (roundedCorners & corner) == corner;
    }

    @Override
    protected void onDraw(Canvas canvas) {
        if (!path.isEmpty()) {
            canvas.clipPath(path);
        }

        super.onDraw(canvas);
    }

    @Override
    protected void onSizeChanged(int w, int h, int oldw, int oldh) {
        super.onSizeChanged(w, h, oldw, oldh);
        setPath();
    }

    private void setPath() {
        path.rewind();

        if (cornerRadius >= 1f && roundedCorners != CORNER_NONE) {
            final float[] radii = new float[8];

            for (int i = 0; i < 4; i++) {
                if (isCornerRounded(CORNERS[i])) {
                    radii[2 * i] = cornerRadius;
                    radii[2 * i + 1] = cornerRadius;
                }
            }

            path.addRoundRect(new RectF(0, 0, getWidth(), getHeight()),
                              radii, Path.Direction.CW);
        }
    }
}
```

For the XML attributes to work, the following needs to be in your `<resources>`, which you can do by putting this file in your project's `res/values/` folder, or adding to the one that might already be there.

`attrs.xml`

```
<resources>
    <declare-styleable name="RoundishImageView">
        <attr name="cornerRadius" format="dimension" />
        <attr name="roundedCorners">
            <flag name="topLeft" value="1" />
            <flag name="topRight" value="2" />
            <flag name="bottomRight" value="4" />
            <flag name="bottomLeft" value="8" />
            <flag name="all" value="15" />
        </attr>
    </declare-styleable>
</resources>
```

The `cornerRadius` is a dimension attribute, and should be specified as a `dp` or `px` value. The `roundedCorners` is a flag attribute, and multiple corners can be chosen using the pipe character, `|`. For example:

```
<com.mycompany.myapp.RoundishImageView
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:id="@+id/riv"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:adjustViewBounds="true"
    android:scaleType="fitXY"
    android:src="@drawable/magritte"
    app:cornerRadius="@dimen/round_corner_radius"
    app:roundedCorners="topLeft|topRight" />
```

---

[image: screenshot]

Comment: Thank you, i have been trying to round the image for 2 weeks now, your code is perfect !!

Comment: @Mike I followed this solution and it is rounding the ImageView having image as background,  as expected .But for the ImageViews which dont have background image and just have background color , It is not working . Do you know why it might happen?

Comment: @user2991413 I'm not sure what you mean. This solution doesn't do anything with the `ImageView`'s background.

Comment: @Mike You are right. I was talking about my usecase where i don't have to set any Image to ImageView . Instead i have to set colors to it . In that case if i do  RoundishImageView.setBackgroundColor(), a rectangle of specified color will appear. I think because Background of imageView is rectangle and this solution will not change it's shape. Do you have any suggestions to handle that case as well ?

Comment: @user2991413 Sure. You can set a `ColorDrawable` as the image, instead of setting the background. For example: `imageView.setImageDrawable(new ColorDrawable(Color.BLUE))`.

Comment: Perfect Solution.!

Answer (score 0):

I also spent a half-day to solve the problem; the key point here is how to use `mPath.arcTo` make a corner. The basic knowledge is E direction is 0 degree, then the second param means which degree start; the third param means how many degrees to show.

```
import android.animation.ValueAnimator;
import android.content.Context;
import android.graphics.Canvas;
import android.graphics.Paint;
import android.graphics.Path;
import android.graphics.PathMeasure;
import android.graphics.RectF;
import android.util.AttributeSet;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.animation.DecelerateInterpolator;

public class RectangleConerView extends View {

private Path mPath;
private Paint mPaint;
private PathMeasure mPathMeasure;
private float mAnimatorValue;
private Path mDst;
private float mLength;

private float left = 300;
private float top = 200;

private float width = 800;
private float height = 300;
private float checkWidth = 100;
private float checkHeight = 60;
private float cornerRadius = 30;

public RectangleConerView(Context context) {
    super(context);
}

public RectangleConerView(Context context, AttributeSet attrs, int defStyleAttr) {
    super(context, attrs, defStyleAttr);
}

public RectangleConerView(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) 
{
    super(context, attrs);
    mPathMeasure = new PathMeasure();
    mPaint = new Paint(Paint.ANTI_ALIAS_FLAG);
    mPaint.setStyle(Paint.Style.STROKE);
    mPaint.setStrokeWidth(5);
    mPath = new Path();

    mPath.moveTo(left + width, top + checkHeight/2);

    //bottom-right
    mPath.lineTo(left + width, top + height - cornerRadius);
    mPath.arcTo(new RectF(left + width-cornerRadius, top + height - cornerRadius, left + width, top + height), 0, 90); //start degree is E direct, then CW 90 degree, which is the bottom-right corner.

    //bottom-left
    mPath.lineTo(left + cornerRadius, top + height);
    mPath.arcTo(new RectF(left, top + height - cornerRadius, left + cornerRadius, top + height), 90, 90);//start degree is the S, then CW 90 degree, which is the bottom-left corner.

    //top-left
    mPath.lineTo(left, top + cornerRadius);
    mPath.arcTo(new RectF(left, top, left + cornerRadius, top + cornerRadius), 180, 90);//start degree W

    //top-right
    mPath.lineTo(left + width - checkWidth/2, top);


    mPathMeasure.setPath(mPath, false);
    mLength = mPathMeasure.getLength();
    mDst = new Path();

    final ValueAnimator valueAnimator = ValueAnimator.ofFloat(0, 1);
    valueAnimator.addUpdateListener(new ValueAnimator.AnimatorUpdateListener() {
        @Override
        public void onAnimationUpdate(ValueAnimator valueAnimator) {
            mAnimatorValue = (float) valueAnimator.getAnimatedValue();
            invalidate();
        }
    });
    valueAnimator.setDuration(1000);
    valueAnimator.setRepeatCount(ValueAnimator.INFINITE);
    valueAnimator.setInterpolator(new DecelerateInterpolator());

    valueAnimator.start();
}

@Override
protected void onDraw(Canvas canvas) {
    super.onDraw(canvas);
    mDst.reset();
    // 硬件加速的BUG
    mDst.lineTo(0,0);
    float stop = mLength * mAnimatorValue;
    mPathMeasure.getSegment(0, stop, mDst, true);
    canvas.drawPath(mDst, mPaint);
}
}
```

[image]