# image in cardview with top radius not showing corner radius

Tags: java, android, cardview, radius

I have recyclerView which insides cardView that has ImageView and it takes 70% height of its. So I have given corner radius to cardView. The bottom of cardView radius is shown but the problem is the top part which is covered by image is not taking the corner radius of cardView.

I tried these questions :  [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41986094/draw-round-corners-on-top-left-top-right-bottom-left-bottom-right-using-path-and) , [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43909723/rounded-scaled-imageview-from-right-side-only). But still the problem remains the same.

xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>

<android.support.v7.widget.CardView
    xmlns:card_view="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/card_view"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="@dimen/_200sdp"
    android:layout_marginRight="@dimen/_15sdp"
    android:layout_marginLeft="15dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="15dp"
    card_view:cardCornerRadius="@dimen/_20sdp"
    card_view:cardBackgroundColor="@color/White"
    android:layout_marginBottom="@dimen/_10sdp">

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:orientation="vertical">

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/party_image"
            android:layout_width="@dimen/_160sdp"
            android:layout_height="@dimen/_140sdp"
            android:adjustViewBounds="true"
            android:scaleType="centerCrop" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/party_text"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:textSize="13sp"
            android:text="John Doe"
            android:textColor="@color/colorPrimary"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:paddingBottom="8dp"
            android:paddingTop="8dp"
            />

    </LinearLayout>

</android.support.v7.widget.CardView>
```

My output image:
https://i.stack.imgur.com/9kZi6.jpg

Comment: Try this, `app:cardCornerRadius=`

Comment: @Kush Vatsa still same no use.

Comment: Have you added the dependencies in build.gradle for cardview and recyclerview?

Comment: of course i have added dependency @Kush vatsa

Comment: Try this, `CardView.setRadius(float)`, https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v7/widget/CardView#setRadius(float)

Comment: I don't understand your question:D Please share your output image

Comment: @propoLis please see this image https://imgur.com/a/FequXmj

Comment: please try my edited answer

Answer (score 2):

Try this..

```html
<FrameLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:id="@+id/card_view"

    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="120dp"
    android:layout_gravity="center"

    android:layout_margin="8dp"
    android:background="@drawable/shape"

    android:elevation="4dp">

    <android.support.v7.widget.CardView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_gravity="center"
        android:elevation="4dp"
        app:cardCornerRadius="8dp">

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/thumbnaill"
            android:layout_width="160dp"
            android:layout_height="140dp"
            android:layout_gravity="left"
            android:background="@drawable/sa"
            android:scaleType="fitXY"
            />
    </android.support.v7.widget.CardView>
</FrameLayout>
```

And in you Drawable make a xml shape.xml

```html
<shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:shape="rectangle" android:padding="10dp">
    <!-- you can use any color you want I used here gray color-->
    <solid android:color="#ffffff"/>
    <corners android:radius="8dp"/>
    <!--<stroke android:width="0.5dp" android:color="@color/darker_gray"/>-->
</shape>
```

It will look like this...Result

[image]

Comment: Doesnt work and the image you are using is not taking complete width of cardview use an image which takes complete width of cardview then see it wont take corner radius of cardview @Faiz Mir

Comment: send me a image which you are using faizmir53@gmail.com

Answer (score 0):

Since android:hardwareAccelerated="true" was added in the manifest, I removed it and it worked

```
<application
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:hardwareAccelerated="true"            //<--
    android:roundIcon="@mipmap/ic_launcher_round"
    android:supportsRtl="true"
    android:theme="@style/Theme.TestLib">
    ...
</application>
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).